# When you distress someone by your words and want to apologize him/her

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Imagine in a meeting, you say something upsetting to a friend who did not expect it from you in a social setting! After the meeting you take the person aside and talk to him / her in private and want to lay stress on the fact that you didn't have any specific intention and apologize to him. Which one of the folloing self made sentences sounds natural to you and if none of them works properly please let me know what shall the person say in such a situation:

> 1- Don't get distressed by/with my words. 
>   2- Don't get upset by/with my words. 
>   3- Don't let my words hurt your feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of those would do.

But it might be more natural, and more polite, to start with "Sorry"

> I'm sorry if I hurt your feelings by what I said...
>   I'm sorry if I upset you ...